How to pass the dynamic parameter name for file uploads in Swagger with Node.js?
properties:
  environment:
    type: string
  fileParam:
    type: string
    format: binary

In the above YAML code I can able to upload the file only as fileParam.
But in my case the param key may be like file or uploadFile or anyThing as per user configuration. So I need to make this key of fileParam into dynamic(Editable) in Swagger with Node.js.
Any ideas?
